Is it possible to keep the vscode backend running on the host even if the ssh connection is closed so that I can recover the output when I reconnect?
I've just migrated from pycharm to vscode, but I'm having a problem: when I'm training a network model in vscode remote, if I disconnect the ssh connection, I can't see the output when I reconnect to the server after. But in Pycharm's remote development, even if I disconnect, I can still keep the IDE backend running so that when I reconnect I can see the previous output. Is there any plugin or setting for vscode that can do this?
